# Nullable @ManyToOne not accepting null value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapstruct

I have a many-to-one relationship that I want to be nullable.
Here's the parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "C_CUSTOMER")
class User { 
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
    private Integer id;
   
    @OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Profile> profiles; 
}
```

And the child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "C_PROFILE")
class Profile {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = true, name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

When I try to save a profile without a userId, the following error is threw:

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : fr.entity.Profile.user -> fr.entity.User
```

If the field userId has a value, then it works smoothly.

I tried a bunch of answers from other questions on SO, but so far nothing has worked. The easiest way would be to ditch the relation in the entity files and use `Integer customerId`, but that's not really satisfactory for me, 'cause it would mean that the cascade deletion wouldn't work anymore.

Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

The problem comes from a entity <-> dto mapping. I added an answer about it, will probably edit if I come across a workaround.

Comment: can you please add the `Profile` pojo in the question?

Comment: Save the `User` first before adding to your `Profile` entity.  Please also make sure that when you're populating your `User` and `Profile`, that you're adding each entity into the other creating the bi-directional relationship.

Comment: The error is only when the `User` is `null`, so I *don't* want to add it. I want the field to be `null`.

Comment: Are you really sure? Because Hibernate complaints that the user is unsaved!

Comment: Well, I've just end a new debug of it and... Turns out that the User field *isn't* null. Mea culpa - it was trying to add a `User` with all the fields at null. Sooo... The question now is : shouldn't `User`be null ? Or i've missed something.

Comment: I tried your code, worked fine for me. Yes the User object itself should be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some digging inside the generated files: there's no solution to it (for now). The problem comes from a mapping between entity <-> dto, using mapstruct: having not mentioned this step, no wonder it wasn't working like it should for me... Well, the profile mapper contains this:

```
protected User profileToUser(Profile profile) {
    if ( profile == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    User user = new User();
    User.setId(profile.getUserId());
    return user;
}
```

Meaning I need to reassign a null value before saving the `Profile`. There is apparently a ticket about this on the github, so wait and see. Seems like there's some suggestions too to make it work, so if I come across one that work, i'll edit this answer (unless someone answer with a solution before).

## EDIT

After a few researches on the mapstruct git and SO, I came across a solution that work, though it's not really elegant.

```
@AfterMapping
public Profile doAfterMapping(@MappingTarget Profile entity) {
    if (entity != null && entity.getUser().getId() == null) {
        entity.setUser(null);
    }
    return entity;
}
```

So... I'll put the question in duplicate. Thanks a bunch to the ones that helped me (though I wouldn't have need to post if I had been more vigilant).

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code on my machine. Below are my entity classes:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name = "C_PROFILE")
@Data
public class Profile {
  @Id 
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  @ManyToOne(optional = true)
  @JoinColumn(nullable = true, name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private User user;
}
```

User class:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name = "C_CUSTOMER")
@Data
class User { 
  @Id 
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
  private Integer id;

  private String email;

  @OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
  private List<Profile> profiles; 
}
```

Repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import io.polarisdev.returns.model.Profile;

public interface ProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<Profile, String> {
}
```

Code to save the Profile without user:

```
Profile p = new Profile();
p.setName("Name");
profileRepository.save(p);
```